# SymbolTable not supported

Tags: soql, developer-console, tooling-api, query-editor

I am trying to find the unused methods using the **Query Editor** in **Developer Console**.

I have checked **Use Tooling API**.

Running *SOQL* like below:

```
SELECT Id FROM SymbolTable WHERE externalReferences = NULL
```

But getting this error:

```
SELECT Id FROM SymbolTable WHERE externalReferences
               ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:16
sObject type 'SymbolTable' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: See similar question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116165/symbol-table-from-apex-class

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32636/symbol-table-references-are-null-rest-call

Comment: Thanks @Sarvesh
I am able to get the results.
But the externalReferences is coming empty, I have manually checked that the class has externalReferences.
Querying like this: `/services/data/v47.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,SymbolTable+FROM+ApexClass+WHERE+Name='MyClass'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the field from the ApexClass object first, as seen here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexclass.htm

Also

> If there is not a cached version of SymbolTable, it will be compiled in the background and the query might take longer than expected. The SymbolTable returned from ApexClass does not contain references; to retrieve a SymbolTable with references, use ApexClassMember.